# ¿Por qué no se realiza el query de update y manda el mensaje "Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, update

Tengo el siguiente servicio en Java que quiero que realize un update, lo mando de la siguiente manera pero no hace nada, no actualiza nada, y en la consola solo aparece el mensaje:

```
2021-07-26 14:07:29.289  INFO 18736 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-07-26 14:07:29.289  INFO 18736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-07-26 14:07:29.742  INFO 18736 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Service java

```java
    @Service
    public class OperationBdServiceImpl implements OperationBdService{
        
        @Override
        public void updateTransactionSucess(String guia, String contrato, String numeroPago, String codigo,
                String fecha) {
            operationRepository.updateTransaction(guia, contrato, numeroPago, codigo, fecha);
            
        }
    }
```

Repository

```java
    @Repository
    public interface OperationRepository extends JpaRepository<Dto, Integer> {

        
        @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
        @Transactional
        @Query(value="UPDATE Dto t SET t.estatus='SUCCESS' WHERE t.guia=?1 AND t.contrato=?2 AND "
                + "t.numeroPago=?3"
                + "AND t.codigo=?4 AND t.fecha=?5 AND t.estatus='PENDIENTE'",  nativeQuery = true)
        void updateTransaction(String guia, String conntrato, String numeroPago, String codigo,
                String fecha,);

    }
```

y no me manda error como tal pero no hace nada y en la cosola solo aparece lo que ya mencione,
que me falta agregar o que esta mal en mi consulta?

ENTIDAD

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="DTO")
    public class Dto implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5215215058728473440L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "GUIA")
        private String guia;

        @Column(name = "NUM_CONTRATO")
        private String contrato;

        @Column(name = "NUM_PAGO")
        private String numeroPago;

        @Column(name = "CODIGO")
        private String codigo;

        @Column(name = "FECHA_REG")
        private String fecha;

        @Column(name = "ESTATUS")
        private String estatus;

        @Column(name = "MENSAJE")
        private String mensaje;

    }
```

Comment: extends JpaRepository<Dto, Integer> , Dto es tu clave @Id?

Comment: Pon el contenido de cada tabla, o sea sus propiedades y tal

Comment: @RoyalUp  agregué mi entidad a la pregunta, esa tabla no tiene una llave primaria como tal  y ocupe el primer atributo como @ Id

Comment: Si pones *@Id* a tu campo guía que es de tipo *String* no deberias poner en tu repository *extends JpaRepository<Dto, String>*?

Comment: Ese es todo el error que aparece? Si no es asi, podrías agregarlo todo?

Comment: @AndresGardiol, ya lo edite, es todo lo que manda el log

Comment: Puedes coloca el POM, para poder revisarlo.